# How can I increment a field value by 1 using SQL Query in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, insert, increment, rpa, automationanywhere

I'm working on a project using Automation Anywhere Client.
I'm extracting data from MS Excel to MS Access using `SELECT` and `UPDATE` statements, but it is possible that the data could repeat itself, and in this case, I would like to `UPDATE` only 3 fields, those are the statements that I'm using

```
    INSERT INTO $vDiagnosis$ 
    VALUES ('$vID$','$vFirstName$','$vLastName$','$vGender$','$vPhone$','$vAge$',
    '$vDateOfVisit$','$vCondition$','$vInsuranceCo$','$vInsuranceNr$','$vVisitingNumber$')
    
    Update $vDiagnosis$ 
    SET DateOfVisit = '$vDateOfVisit$', Condition = '$vCondition$' 
    WHERE ID = '$vID$'
```

which are the **DateOfVisit** and the **Condition** and the **VisitingNumber** (which is the number of times someone visited that hospital). The thing is, I'm trying to increment the **VisitingNumber** every time the `UPDATE` statement is executed, for example, someone visits today, I want it to be 1, the `UPDATE` statement is executed again, I want that 1 to increment.

I tried making a variable, and to increment it every time the `UPDATE` is being executed but whenever it loops and goes to the next `INSERT` statement, it continues incrementing, even if it inserts a new value.

[A preview of the work I'm trying to do on Automation Anywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBtuR.png)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Code should be posted as text within question, not an image. You want each set of patient visit records to have own number sequence? Need to reset the incrementing variable when the patient changes.

Comment: Well, sadly I cannot post the code, cause on Automation Anywhere it's a list of drag & drop commands, so i can't really paste them, I tried. that's why I posted something a picture of it. 
You tried to help me the other time, but I lost the license of the application, and I couldn't continue, that's why now I'm back, 
You're right, i want each patient to have own number sequence, like if there are 3 entries, and 2 people, but one visited twice, i want this guy's VisitingNumber to be 2, and the other guy to be 1.

Comment: As I said, reset incrementing variable when patient changes. This could involve a variable holding patient ID and comparing to patient ID in record. When they don't match, reset the increment as well as the patient ID variable. I know nothing about AutomationAnywhere. I would use VBA.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need. It's been a long time since I've used VBA, I even forgot about it. I might just forget about that VisitingNumber in case it holds me from finishing this thing, but thanks for your help man, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the variable aspect mentioned, but bumping the `VisitingNumber` count should be able to be done as:

```
UPDATE $vDiagnosis$ 
   SET DateOfVisit = '$vDateOfVisit$',
       Condition = '$vCondition$',
       VisitingNumber = VisitingNumber + 1
 WHERE ID = '$vID$'
```

To the insert, the value for the `visitingNumber` could simply be 1 without a variable, like so:

```
INSERT INTO $vDiagnosis$ 
VALUES ('$vID$','$vFirstName$','$vLastName$','$vGender$','$vPhone$','$vAge$',
'$vDateOfVisit$','$vCondition$','$vInsuranceCo$','$vInsuranceNr$', 1)
```

Or better, perhaps a default value of 1 could be specified at the table level, and then it would not need to be included with the insert query at all. (it would be set to 1 at insert)

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help. As far as i remember, I tried "VisitingNumber + 1" but when the data gets transferred, it get's transferred as "VisitingNumber + 1", But i think I did it with a single quote, can't remember, I'll try it again as soon as the server gets back up in AutomationAnywhere.